# Post json data getting csrf token missing or invalid

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

Would appreciate if someone can help me find the problem. I know there are a lot of solutions regarding this specific problem. Have been stuck here for a quite a long time now.

My code

Views

```
class HolidayList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Holiday.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HolidaySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication,BasicAuthentication]
```

url

```
url(r'^$', HolidayList.as_view(), name='holiday-list-api'),
```

Getting this error

```
{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
```

my rest framework configuration

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'base.csrf_exempt.CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    ),
}
```

Tried to use CsrfExempt but no luck. What am i missing here ?

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication

class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):
   def enforce_csrf(self, request):
     return
```

Comment: I was using SessionAuthentication in authentication classes, and CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication in settings. just had to remove SessionAuthentication from authntication classes. Working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and solved with the following jquery snippet

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")}});
    });

    function getCookie(name) {
        function escape(s) { return s.replace(/([.*+?\^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1'); };
        var match = document.cookie.match(RegExp('(?:^|;\\s*)' + escape(name) + '=([^;]*)'));
        return match ? match[1] : null;
    }
</script>
```

csrf_token is stored in the cookie called "csrftoken" and you need to pass it to the request header. In your case to your POST request header.

hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks but solved the problem by adding CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication in authentication classes.